# Being capable enough to do something "in anger"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “used in anger” a Britishism for something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30939/is-used-in-anger-a-britishism-for-something)

My boss keeps using the terminology "Doug knows X but maybe not enough to use it 'in anger'", where X is a skill, programming language, etc.

I've not heard the phrase "in anger" used this way before. He seems to be saying I am a novice or am intermediate at a skill. If I were an expert I could really achieve a sense of focussed flow to solve a problem in a high stress/frustrating situation. Hence I could effectively wield the tool "in anger" to solve a problem.

Is this a correct interpretation of the meaning of this phrase in this context? What exactly does my boss mean?

Comment: You may care to have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30939/is-used-in-anger-a-britishism-for-something).

Comment: Liken it to this: Doug knows how to use a sword, but maybe not enough to kill someone with it. In other words, to *use it in anger* means to really do something with it – to achieve the purpose of knowing the skill.

Comment: I haven't made any effort to check, but I suspect to *use in anger* is primarily a British usage. I base that on the fact that most voters here on ELU are probably American (or at least, more familiar with US than UK usage), and for several days the *for real* (as opposed to *aggressively*) meaning wasn't even mentioned on the earlier question. In short, only the "literal" interpretation seems to have truly global currency.

Comment: [Related](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iul4SBlHIf8).